# Animate pseudo element on hover

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I have an input with a pseudo element that I'm trying to animate on hover.. I wanted the white line on the input to infinitely scroll to the right out of view and come back in on the left etc.. Is this possible?

```css
.buttonWrap {
    position: relative;
}
.buttonWrap:before {
    content: '';
    width: 20px;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: .5rem;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.buttonWrap:hover::before {
    animation: J 1s ease 0s infinite normal none;
}

.uiBtn.redBtn {
    background: #1a1a1a;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
    color: #fff;
    min-width: 16.25rem;
    font-size: .6875rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 1rem;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<span class="buttonWrap">
<input type="submit" class="uiBtn redBtn" value="Submit">
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example using `transform` property (I've slow down the duration just to check the fluidity)

```css
.buttonWrap {
    position: relative;
}
.buttonWrap:before {
    content: '';
    width: 20px;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 1px);
    right: .5rem;
}
.buttonWrap:hover::before {
    animation: J 5s linear 0s infinite;
}

.uiBtn.redBtn {
    background: #1a1a1a;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
    color: #fff;
    min-width: 16.25rem;
    font-size: .6875rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 1rem;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding:10px;
}

@keyframes J {
   0% { transform: translateX(0); right: .5rem; }
   10% { transform: translateX(calc(100% + .5rem)); right: .5rem; }
   10.01% { transform: translateX(-100%); right: 100%;  }
   93% { transform: translateX(-100%); right: .5rem; }
}
```

```html
<span class="buttonWrap">
<input type="submit" class="uiBtn redBtn" value="Submit">
</span>
```

Comment: Hey Fcalderan, that's fantastic. The only thing is, it's scrolling out of the button and coming back in.. It's meant to scroll back in where the line starts if that makes sense..Perhaps I need a wrapper around the icon but that's brilliant, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

FYI; here's what ended up working for me! .. animation happens when you hover over the button..

```css
.underline::after {
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 30px;
  top:50%;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all;
}

.underline {
  position: absolute;
  right: .5rem;
  top: 50%;
  width: 30px;
}

.underlined-animated:hover .underline::after {
  animation: underline-animated 1s infinite;
  width: auto;
  animation-delay: -.5s;
}

.underlined-animated {
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes underline-animated {
  0% {
    right: 100%;
  }
  50% {
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    right: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }
}

.uiBtn.redBtn {
    background: #1a1a1a;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
    color: #fff;
    min-width: 16.25rem;
    font-size: .6875rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 1rem;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<span class="underlined-animated">
  <span class="underline"></span>
<input type="submit" class="uiBtn redBtn" value="Submit">
</span>
```